# How to get consent strings from Flurry's privacy dashboard?

Tags: android, flurry

I have been using the smaato privacy dash for my Flurry analytics implementation successfully by [integrating this github project](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework) into my app, I can successfully get the consent strings when the user closes the webpage. But I would like to use the official Flurry privacy dashboard to do the same thing instead. I am using the latest flurry sdk version 11.1.1 and this is the working code to open Flurry's privacy dashboard:

```
public void openCollectedDataDashboard() {
    final FlurryPrivacySession.Callback callback = new FlurryPrivacySession.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success() {
        Log.i("yoyo", "Collected data Dashboard opened successfully");
    }
    @Override
    public void failure() {
    Log.i("yoyo", "Opening Collected data Dashboard failed");
    }
    };
    final FlurryPrivacySession.Request request = new FlurryPrivacySession.Request(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.getApplicationContext(), callback);
    FlurryAgent.openPrivacyDashboard(request);
}
```

But how do I get the consent strings once the user closes the web page?

The current way I'm doing it with the github project integration to open the Flurry compatible Smaato privacy dash is like so:

```
public void openPrivacyDashboard() {
    CMPStorage.setCmpPresentValue( RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity , true);
    CMPSettings cmpSettings = new CMPSettings(SubjectToGdpr.CMPGDPREnabled, "https://demofiles.smaato.com/cmp/index.html", null);
    CMPConsentToolActivity.openCmpConsentToolView(cmpSettings,  RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity , new OnCloseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onWebViewClosed() {
            }
        });
    Map<String, String> consentStrings = new HashMap<>();
    consentStrings.put("IAB", CMPStorage.getConsentString( RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity ));
    new FlurryAgent.Builder().withLogEnabled(true).withCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true)
            .withContinueSessionMillis(10000).withConsent(new FlurryConsent(true, consentStrings))
                .build( RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity , m_apiKey);
}
```

It successfully gets the updated consent strings and then re - inits the Flurry session with the new string. [Here is an example .apk I made](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R4imaIXY2FWhG9Wqh7CnYP38JW9jCuSL) to show the current situation.

How do I do this with Flurry's privacy dashboard?

Comment: Anyone have any idea on how to do this? I'm pretty sure I'm not the ONLY person using flurry in 2018, or... maybe I am???

Comment: Did you solve the issue? We have the same issue but in iOS. iOS demo app (https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/tree/master/In-App%20Reference/iOS/CMPConsentToolDemoApp) redirects with consent strings only if consentToolURL is set to https://demofiles.smaato.com/cmp/index.html. I tried to set https://policies.oath.com/ie/en/oath/privacy/index.html (mentioned in https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/gdpr/?guccounter=1) but it doesn't work.